# Add an object to addpoint API of highchart is not working

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock to draw a histogram, when i try add a new point using addpoint api,i need to add a new object that contains x, y and color.
This is the way i do it:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint({color: color, y: value, x: time });
```

but i get this error taht says:`Can't add object point configuration to a long data series`
Highcharts error #20: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/20

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And as error points, increase or disable [`turboThreshold`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold).